# Firefox was restored to default after update

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, updates, personal-data

I noted a strange behavior on my Firefox after the last update.

I was using the Firefox Dev Edition (I'm not sure about the version, but maybe it was 52), but after a simple update throug `apt-get udpate && apt-get upgrade`, it looks like a fresh installation of simple Firefox (not dev edition).

I lost the bookmarks, extensions, passwords and all the things and even the Firefox skin (and Unity Icon laucher) was restored to default instead the black theme of Dev Edition.

I don't know what happend, but I was using sync and now I'm afraid to do the login and lose my stuff in my other devices (Another Ubuntu and Android, FYI).

I not found the ["Old Firefox Data"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1046853) anywhere.

Anyone know what should I do? Should I try the sync login without risk of return all my devices to default?

MISC

> - Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)
> - Mozilla Firefox 54 (after upgrade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the reason, but apparently, the update just created a new profile with the default options.

I did not need to do the login, I just selected my old profile.

Below is the task list for anyone with similar problem:

- Open the terminal;
- Close any running istance of firefox (killall -9 firefox if you had problems);
- `firefox -profilemanager` will open a window with probably more then one profile. The select one was named "default" in my case;
- Ensure the check in the box beside "Don't ask at startup."
- Choose another profile ("dev-default" is the name of mine) and double-click it;
- Done. i was signed up in sync with all my stuffs back. The only 
  "problem" now is the icon in the unity laucher that is still the orange one, but its a minor issue that not affectcs my expericence for now.